# WPF Combobox behavior weird

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes which we will call cbo1 and cbo2. Now, there is a relationship between cbo1 and cbo2. when i select an item at cbo1, the cbo2 ItemsSource is updated (since it is bound to the SelectedItem) anyway, below is the sample XAML code for it.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Brand}"></ComboBox>
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Model}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbo1, Path=SelectedItem.Models}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ComboBox>
```

the objects used are Brand and Model. Brand has a property named Models which contain a collection of Model objects ( typeof IList ). So basically, a one-many relationship between the 2 classes.

By the way, those 2 classes are used in NHibernate. Now, when I run the app, cbo1 which contains a collection of Brand objects is loaded with the items first. When I select a Brand item, the cbo2 with the Model collection is populated. As you have noticed, both Comboboxes have SelectedItem property bound to the current object properties Brand and Model specifically. When I select a Model on the cbo2, it does not reflect to the current object's Model property. Anything i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo: the first combo is called cbo1, but the second combo is binding to cbxBrand; but since you say the Models *do* appear, I'm guessing this is OK in your actual source code, and you renamed it for the Question here?

Anyway, your code completely worked for me, I put a breakpoint on the setter of the Model property and it hit it no probs, so the only thing I can possibly guess at is the Window's DataContext maybe incorrect?
Can you post your code-behind (or ViewModel) ?

Comment: oh sorry, cbxBrand was actually cbo1... renamed it for the question here.

Comment: cool.. so did you double-check the DataContext? to re-iterate: The code you have written is totally correct, as long as you are Binding to (ie have set the DataContext to be) the object exposing properties 'Brand' and 'Model'

Comment: yes, I have set the DataContext at the parent Grid element containing both ComboBoxes. I dont know why the selected Model item at the cbo2 element does not reflect at the Model property of the DataContext. that's what made it weird.